# In Ckeditor How to openDialog with another is closed

Tags: ckeditor

When Image dialog is closed how can i automate the opening of Link dialog.

I have tried

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
if ( dialogName == 'image' )
{

dialogDefinition.onOk = function(ev) {
editor.openDialog( 'link' );
}
}
});
```

But it fails.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name,
        dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition,
        editor = ev.editor;

    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
        var oldOk = dialogDefinition.onOk;

        dialogDefinition.onOk = function() {
            oldOk.call( this );
            setTimeout( function() {
                editor.execCommand( 'link' );
            }, 0 );
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you are a life saver, I will be very kind of you to answer this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827629/ckeditor-colorbox-integration

Comment: Thanks again the functionality works perfect, but it didnot solved my problem. Actually I am trying to use colorbox load with image. please have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827629/ckeditor-colorbox-integration]. Great help

Comment: how can it be done, so that the inserted image is selected for executing link dialog.. please anyone